# Common 6-wire sockets/connectors

Tags: connector, wiring, socket

I'm currently playing around with some load cells in a wheatstone bridge - each cell has 3 wires (sub-1mm thickness). I want to mount these cells onto 2 separate pieces that can be spaced apart to allow them to fit under different sized objects more easily - so I want to connect the 6 wires on one piece over to the other, 30-60cm away.

I'm looking for a 'standard' connector of some kind that can carry 6 wires to connect one piece to the other, so I can mount a socket onto each piece. I'd like to just buy the wires with connectors already attached, and ideally the sockets will come in a form where I can easily attach the wires to them without having to have a custom board made up or require an expensive crimp tool (I'm not sure the load cell wires would be suitable for crimping anyway).

Any suggestions on common connector format that could work here?

Comment: Why not just go to Mouser or Digi-key, click on the connectors section, and look at their offerings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ethernet RJ style jacks and cables are pretty common. Some more than others.

They are called Modular Jacks and Cables.

https://www.mouser.com/Connectors/Modular-Connectors-Ethernet-Connectors/_/N-wos3?Keyword=rj45&FS=True

[image: IDC solid wire type [![enter image description here][1]][1]]

[image: There are also null modem cables so the cells can be plugged directly or via jacks and cable.] 
[image]

1m Shielded CAT6 cable may have some benefit in high noise areas.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I had completely failed to think of RJ45 and friends for this task... though they make perfect sense being (optionally) shielded and having a very common fitting!

Answer (score 1):

Try Molex MiniFit connectors, they are fairly common and easy to work with. If you're looking for something smaller their MicroFit and NanoFit are also good options.